# Comparing Test and Control Lift in Proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I have two groups - a test/treated and control group - for which I am trying to assess whether the **lift** or percent change in proportion from a pre to post period between the two groups are unequal.

I'm defining the lift for group $g$ as

$L_g = \frac{p_{post, g} - p_{pre, g}}{p_{pre, g}}$

And my null/alternative hypothesis are:

$H_0: L_{control} = L_{test}$

$H_1: L_{control} \neq L_{test}$

The two groups are independent of each other. My thought is that this is just a z-test for two independent continuous variables, so the test statistic would be given by

$z = \frac{\bar{L_t} - \bar{L_c}}{S_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_t} + \frac{1}{n_c}}}$

$S_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_t-1)s_t^2+(n_c-1)s_c^2}{n_t+n_c-2}}$

Where $\bar{L_g}= \frac{\bar{p}_{post, g} - \bar{p}_{pre, g}}{\bar{p}_{pre, g}}$ is the sample mean lift for group $g$

My issue is that I'm not quite sure how to compute the sample variances $s_t$ and $s_c$ for this metric, if I'm even correct in my thinking up to this point.

Can anyone advise?